# Good character personality types to balance a group dynamic?

Tags: characters

I’m working on a story involving a central quartet of characters. Though I have a concept for the fourth of these, they don’t have a set personality and I would like to have them balance out the dynamic somewhat.

The present characters are as such:

- Elegant and classy in demeanour with a hidden mischievous streak. Lives for the fun of things without thinking too much about the consequences. Charismatic. Likes running circles around people with superior wit, though will fall into line reluctantly in order to protect their image.
- Quiet, serious individual who is somewhat fearful of other people. Observant, logical, excessively cautious.  Has pretty good problem-solving skills, though a tad too careful to get much use out of them, but would perish instantly if they had to ask for extra ketchup at a fast food place.
- Responsible and intelligent person, pretty good mediator and often the one to make final decisions since (currently) the only other perspectives are caution bordering on indecision, and sheer reckless abandon. Motherly. A bit reserved, prefers their own company. Won’t hesitate to shoot down a bad idea when they hear it.

I haven’t been able to figure out an obvious opening in this dynamic that would need to be filled, but there’s an in-universe reason that there needs to be four people in the group. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I think it depends on the setting what would make a good fourth. And maybe in the end you might need to redistribute some characteristics to balance things out. But here's a shot: does a reckless short-tempered dim/average-witted character fit into the story?

Answer (score 1):

### [Myers-Briggs type indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%E2%80%93Briggs_Type_Indicator)

[image]

The easiest solution is to check what options you have left according to the chart above. Let me do some of the work for you:

Character 1: E N F P

Character 2: I N T J

Character 3: E S T P

Now, we take for each position the characteristic that was only used once. That is ISFJ.

What is an ISFJ?

It could be either a healer-fighter, e.g. a cleric in a fantasy RPG, or perhaps a [Guardian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keirsey_Temperament_Sorter#Guardian).